# In Matlab, how to change plot intervals?

Tags: matlab, plot, intervals, subplot

I've been writin' a Matlab function that reads a file and plots its 3D graphics, with three projection.

In the four graphics provided, it plots all the data, and decides the x,y,z interval from these data points.
I woul like to change these plottin' intervals, but I don't know how to do it.

See this figure:
[image]

In this case my problem is that on the 4th image (zy plane) I would like to see the y points in interval [1...0], instead of viewin' in interval [1...0.4].

Here's my code for the plottin' on my 4th image of the four:

```
  subplot(2,2,4) 
  plot3(FNrate, FPrate, tau);
  view(-90,0); % we rotates the figure from standard to -90° (270°);
  title('zy plane'); 
  xlabel('x = FP (AP) rate'), ylabel('y = FN (AR) rate'), zlabel('z = tau'), grid on
```

How could I do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ylim([0 1])
```

should do the trick, look up the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/ylim.html)